# how allow email using email validation regex in android

Tags: java, android

```
 public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        String expression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

this is my code for email validation its working fine but when i try to enter sanjeev@san-szabo.com  then its not allowing  using regex can any one please help me how to allow this email using above regex what i need to change .

Thanks

Comment: duplicate question for sure !!

Comment: Just an aside-  that pattern isn't even close to right, email addresses are very complicated.  You'll work for the majority of them, but not all of them with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a *hypen* to the second *character-class*, and remove the `+` *quantifier* from the `\.`.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z-]+\.[a-z]+
```

Additionally, just use *[String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))*.

```java
return email.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z-]+\\.[a-z]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt email regex pattern (provided by *android.util*) to match your email.

```
Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()
```

Also, you can check for an empty email before trying to validate it against a regex.